# Context click not working in iframe for chrome extension if the frame is blank

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my chrome extension, Context menu click is working fine in all the pages as well as in frames but if the frame has no url **(frame URL: about:blank)** its not working with right click, By mousedown event listener I am identifying the html element **(html node)**, based on that I am building the **XPath**.

Manifest.json

```
  "all_frames": true,
  "match_about_blank": true,
```

permission also given, still facing the issues.
any help on this will be great.

Comment: "not working" is too vague so you need to clarify what exactly happens, show the code that doesn't work, and so on.

Comment: not sure how to explain this, While debugging as I do right click use the context click option it's going to the background page, and coming back to the context page, but the mouse event listener not identifying the element. 
but same is working in firefox browser.

Comment: // add xpath on context menu click
```ortoni.init = function () {
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", function (event) {
        console.log('Events: ' + event);

        clickedElement = event.target;
        console.log(clickedElement);
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: Could be a bug in Chrome. See if it's reported on https://crbug.com or report it yourself.

Comment: Hi, I have reported the same, [link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=996659),

Comment: @wOxxOm hi, Can you help on this problem, I reported but they said its extension problem, can you please help on this. 
I have attached sample extension as well as sample video stating the problem, Pls have a look on this. Thank you.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=996659

Comment: They said it's related to extensions in general and assigned a programmer who deals with extensions. Now all you can do is wait. It may take many weeks or months.